# Can't fetch image URL and use it as CSS background image

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, background-image, fetch

I have a Unordered List wist List Items that are created using the Fetch method. The data is JSON data and needs to be relayed to an HTML document

I want the created list items to have a CSS-background based on the JSON data URL. It looks something like this;

```
fetch(url).then(function(response){
    return response.json();
    JSON.stringify(data);
}).then(function(data){

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var createListItem = document.createElement("li");
        createListItem.className = "listItem";
        var listItem = document.querySelector(".listItem");

        var createHeaderItem = document.createElement("h3");
        createHeaderItem.innerHTML = data[i].title;

        ul.appendChild(createListItem);
        createListItem.appendChild(createHeaderItem);

        if (data[i] && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {
            listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+""data[i].media[0].url""+"')";

        } else {
            listItem.style.backgroundImage = "none";
    }
}
});
```

I can't get the list item style background to relay the URL. What is the correct way of grabbing the data.media.url and using it as CSS list-item property?

Comment: surely you did some debugging on your own before posting.. what did `console.log(data[i].media[0].url)` output?

Comment: If I replace listItem.style.backgroundImage with console.log(data[i].media[0].url) I get a string of the url in the console log. I want to relay the url as a CSS background image

Comment: `listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"data[i].media[0].url"')";` there is a SyntaxError here, I guess it's a typo when writing the question, but please paste the actual code you tried.

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it doesn't work. After inserting this none of the JSON data loads and the console returns error message SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'data'. It doesn't recognise the parameter.

Comment: I changed the syntax hoping to reflect the issue better

Comment: Looks like a typo, what you want is probably: `"url('" + data[i].media[0].url + "')"`

Comment: `var listItem = document.querySelector(".listItem");` is null as you've not added `createListItem` to the DOM. You may have better luck with `createListItem.style.backgroundImage = "..";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have excessive quotes

Try removing the quote after the first + and before the second +

```
  listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+""data[i].media[0].url""+"')";
```

To

```
  listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ data[i].media[0].url +"')";
```

Edited:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var createListItem = document.createElement("li");
    createListItem.className = "listItem";

    var createHeaderItem = document.createElement("h3");
    createHeaderItem.innerHTML = data[i].title;

    ul.appendChild(createListItem);
    createListItem.appendChild(createHeaderItem);



    var listItem = document.querySelector(".listItem");


    if (data[i] && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {
        listItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ data[i].media[0].url +"')";

    } else {
        listItem.style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
```

What has changed?

You never declared

```
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
```

I'm going to assume this is global variable and declared outside this scope otherwise you have additional problems that needs addressing.

I've moved the following code (see below) further down the code. You attempted to access a DOM element using document.querySelector() on an element that has not yet been added to the DOM. As a result of this you always got null returned.

```
    var listItem = document.querySelector(".listItem");
```

This excessive quote I raised earlier still stands.

Comment: No background image and fetch data fails to load.
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'listItem.style')

Comment: @Nathan you're getting `null is not an object` because of your querySelector. `listItem` has not yet been added to the DOM so you cannot run a query for it.

Comment: So how can I make it that it loads list items first and then checks for a background image?

Comment: Your question title and the error message are two different things. See my edited response as to why you get null.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in my comments `listItem` is `null`. This is due to the fact that `createListItem` has yet to be added to the DOM and `.querySelector(..)` checks the current DOM tree when the function is called.

There is no need for `listItem` to exist since you're manipulating and appending to `createListItem`. So rather than trying to assign `.style.backgroundImage = ".."` to `listItem` add it to `createListItem`:

```
if (data[i] && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {
    createListItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+data[i].media[0].url+"')";
} else {
    createListItem.style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
```

Additionally if `.listItem`, the CSS class, does not have a default `background-image` of some sort you can omit the above `else` clause as it is unnecessary:

```
if (data[i] && data[i].media[0] && data[i].media[0].url) {
    createListItem.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+data[i].media[0].url+"')";
}
```